# .Remove() function not working for MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is constantly giving me error that Contact.remove() is not a function. I want to delete a particular contact by passing an id.

```
const DeleteContact = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    const contact = await Contact.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!contact) {
       res.status(404)
       throw new Error("Contact not found");
    }
  
 
    await Contact.remove();
    res.status(200).json(contact);
});
```

Comment: You should note that this is Mongoose, not vanilla Mongo. And if you check the docs, you'll see it uses the word "delete", not "remove". And obviously, you need to tell it *what* to delete. You may want to change from `findById` to a deletion that uses a condition like `{_id: req.params.id}`.

Comment: In addition to what @Carcigenicate wrote, you probably want to invoke the function on the object `contact`, not `Contact`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
const DeleteContact = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const contact = await Contact.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id });
  if (!contact) {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("Contact not found");
  }

  res.status(200).json(contact);
});
```

Your error is probably because of using `delete` instead of `deleteOne`, i think they recently had a change on their function names

Comment: This is making an unnecessary second call to the database. One to check if document exists then another to delete. Mongoose has `Model.findByIdAndDelete()` and `Model.findOneAndDelete()` to simplify the process.

Comment: well, I searched for `findOneAndRemove` when making this response and couldn't find lmao, I always swap delete by remove. I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Model.findByIdAndDelete()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndDelete()) if you know the `_id` of the document to would like to delete like so:

```js
const DeleteContact = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
   try{
      const contact = await Contact.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
      if (!contact) {
         return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'Unable to delete. Contact not found.'
         })
      }
      res.status(200).json(contact);
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({
         message: 'Error on server.'
      })
   }
});
```

**Note**: the `try/catch` may be unnecessary if your `asyncHandler` is well written but I did not want to assume.